# Export all dynamic Azure AD groups with owner and the membership rule (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, membership

can anyone help me get a csv export with all the Azure AD groups and their dynamic membership rules? being of course "Security" type, dynamic membership type

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
Get-AzureADMSGroup -Filter "groupTypes/any(c:c eq 'DynamicMembership')" -All:$true | Select-Object Displayname,MembershipRule
```

Comment: Trying today, huge thanks for your help